# Hostname resolution not working from within Elasticsearch client under Docker

Tags: php, laravel, docker, elasticsearch

Having some trouble with ElasticSearch running within a Laravel application on Docker. I've had the same application running seamlessly on a local environment and I'm currently in the process of setting up UAT and production instances of the application, this question relates to a UAT instance.

I'm using Docker in swarm mode and have several containers, two of which are PHP and Elasticsearch. Within `docker-compose.yml` I've set the name of the Elasticsearch container to `portal_elasticsearch`.

**Here is the problem**

If I `exec` into the PHP container and ping `portal_elasticsearch` I can see that the system itself can resolve the IP from the hostname;

```
$ ping portal_elasticsearch
PING portal_elasticsearch (10.0.1.65) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.1.65 (10.0.1.65): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.124 ms
```

What's more is that I can query elasticsearch via curl and get a response;

```
$ curl portal_elasticsearch:9200/_cat/indices?v
health status index            uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
yellow open   remortgage_index VPvFRhhaQ5257zvmQuUkIQ   5   1         17            0    182.7kb        182.7kb
```

PHP even resolves it correctly;

```
$ php -r 'echo gethostbyname("portal_elasticsearch") . "\n";'
10.0.1.65
```

However if I hit an endpoint on the Laravel app I get the following error (I've redacted some stuff further down the stack which isn't relevant), suffice to say I've stepped through the whole application and it throws an error when inspecting the HTTP response code coming back from Elasticsearch;

```
{
    "message": "No alive nodes found in your cluster",
    "status_code": 500,
    "debug": {
        "line": 52,
        "file": "/var/www/api/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/ConnectionPool/StaticNoPingConnectionPool.php",
        "class": "Elasticsearch\\Common\\Exceptions\\NoNodesAvailableException",
        "trace": [
            "#0 /var/www/api/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Transport.php(76): Elasticsearch\\ConnectionPool\\StaticNoPingConnectionPool->nextConnection()",
            "#1 /var/www/api/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Transport.php(94): Elasticsearch\\Transport->getConnection()",
            "#2 /var/www/api/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php(245): Elasticsearch\\Transport->performRequest('PUT', '//portal_elasti...', Array, '{\"id\":\"2b6bcc41...', Array)",
            "#3 /var/www/api/vendor/react/promise/src/FulfilledPromise.php(25): Elasticsearch\\Connections\\Connection->Elasticsearch\\Connections\\{closure}(Array)",
            "#4 /var/www/api/vendor/guzzlehttp/ringphp/src/Future/CompletedFutureValue.php(55): React\\Promise\\FulfilledPromise->then(Object(Closure), NULL, NULL)",
            "#5 /var/www/api/vendor/guzzlehttp/ringphp/src/Core.php(341): GuzzleHttp\\Ring\\Future\\CompletedFutureValue->then(Object(Closure), NULL, NULL)",
            "#6 /var/www/api/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php(298): GuzzleHttp\\Ring\\Core::proxy(Object(GuzzleHttp\\Ring\\Future\\CompletedFutureArray), Object(Closure))",
            "#7 /var/www/api/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php(176): Elasticsearch\\Connections\\Connection->Elasticsearch\\Connections\\{closure}(Array, Object(Elasticsearch\\Connections\\Connection), Object(Elasticsearch\\Transport), Array)",
            "#8 /var/www/api/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Transport.php(110): Elasticsearch\\Connections\\Connection->performRequest('PUT', '/remortgage_ind...', Array, '{\"id\":\"2b6bcc41...', Array, Object(Elasticsearch\\Transport))",
            "#9 /var/www/api/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Client.php(1553): Elasticsearch\\Transport->performRequest('PUT', '/remortgage_ind...', Array, Array, Array)",
            "#10 /var/www/api/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Client.php(791): Elasticsearch\\Client->performRequest(Object(Elasticsearch\\Endpoints\\Index))",
            "#11 /var/www/api/app/DomainImplementation/Infrastructure/ElasticSearchClient.php(41): Elasticsearch\\Client->index(Array)",
            "#12 /var/www/api/app/DomainImplementation/ReadModel/RemortgageElasticSearchRepository.php(45): App\\DomainImplementation\\Infrastructure\\ElasticSearchClient->index('2b6bcc41-f0de-4...', 'remortgage_inde...', 'remortgage', Array)",
            << SNIP >>
        ]
    }
}
```

***However***

If I change my `.env` file to the internal IP address (`10.0.1.65` as above) of the Elasticsearch Docker container then it works fine.

**TL;DR:** PHP Elasticsearch client won't work with hostname but will with an IP address, even though PHP and the OS can resolve the hostname.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** I managed to fix it, ensure that hostnames don't have any underscores.

After a few hours of messing around I stumbled upon the following in the documentation for the official elasticsearch PHP client;

> Unfortunately, these built-in methods run into problems with certain
>   edge-cases. For example, `filter_var()` will not accept URL’s that have
>   underscores (which are questionably legal, depending on how you
>   interpret the RFCs).

In my question you can see that the hostname for the elasticsearch Docker container is `portal_elasticsearch`. I have managed to fix my issue by changing the hostname to `portal-elasticsearch`. Alternatively I could have conceivably used [Extended Host Configuration](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/configuration.html#_extended_host_configuration) to configure Elasticsearch to use a hostname with an underscore, although as the elasticsearch documentation points out the legality of this is questionable depending on how the RFCs are interpreted.